# MaxID for an given user

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

From the following data i want to get the MaxID of EmpID 1100

```
ID  | EmpId  
1   | 1002   
5   | 1100   
6   | 1109   
7   | 1100   
9   | 1100   
10  | 1250   
11  | 1250   
12  | 1100
```

Results should be

```
ID
9
```

Please help

Comment: u want in sql or EF?

Comment: select max(ID) from dbo.table name where empid=1100

Comment: for linq you can use  Max function with where clause

Comment: How, i m new in linq

Comment: add it in answer please check

Comment: Shouldn't the result equals to 12 instead 9 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it this way. Important thing to note is you must have elemnts to run `Max` on a collection.

```
var recs = ctx.Employees.Where(e => e.EmpId == IdToBeSearched).Select(e => e.Id).ToList();
if(recs.Any())
{
    return recs.Max();
}
```

Or

```
var recs = ctx.Employees.Where(e => e.EmpId == IdToBeSearched).Select(e => e.Id).OrderByDescending().FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this,
`employee` is the table name and `ctx` is the `dbcontext` of EF

    var maxid=  (from p in ctx.employee
                 where p.empid== 1100
                 select p.Id).Max();

// you can use it like this 
   var nRow = (from f in db.FeeAccount where f.FeeMainUserID == maxid);
```

Comment: Not working, it says 'int' doesn't contain a definition for 'Max'

Comment: you may be missing some reference

Comment: var nRow = (from f in db.FeeAccount
                        where f.FeeMainUserID == userid
                        select f.FeeAccountID.Max();

Comment: this is not what my answer was . you need to get first Id then use that id in your query . I updated it in my answer

Comment: @Grewal great to hear . please accept my answer if you feel and it was helpful